# Sentinel Value Implementation

Tags: java

**Problem:**
Write a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of non-negative integers.  The user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series.  Besides -99 as sentinel value, do not accept any negative integers as input (implement input validation).  After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest numbers entered.

**Trouble:** Having trouble with implementing the loop. The sentinel value works to get out of the loop, but it still retains that value as min and max. Can anyone help me please? I'm first time user and trying to learn Java.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserEntryLoop
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        /// Declaration ///
        int userEntry = 0, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        /// Shortcut that shows all of these are int.
        /// Integer.Min_VALUE is the lowest possible number for an int
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Read an initial data
    System.out.print(
            "Enter a positive int value (the program exits if the input is -99): ");
    userEntry = input.nextInt();
    // Keep reading data until the input is -99
    while (userEntry != -99) {

        // Read the next data
        System.out.print(
                "Enter a positive int value (the program exits if the input is -99): ");
        userEntry= input.nextInt();
    }


    if (userEntry > max) //// if the max was < X it would print the initialized value.
        max = userEntry;   /// To fix this the max should be Integer.MAX_VALUE or MIN_VALUE for min

    if (userEntry < min)
        min = userEntry;


    System.out.println("The max is : " + max);
    System.out.println("The min is : " + min);
}
}
```

Comment: Evaluate `min` and `max` _inside_ the loop.

Comment: As @Marvin pointed out, you need to get the `if` conditions involving `max` and `min` inside your loop.

Comment: I put it inside the loop now. The max works. But the min it still calculates as the sentinel value of -99. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should test in your loop (and I'd use `Math.min` and `Math.max` respectively, instead of a chain of `if`s). Also, don't forget to check that the value isn't negative. Something like,

```
while (userEntry != -99) {
    // Read the next data
    System.out.print("Enter a positive int value (the program exits "
            + "if the input is -99): ");
    userEntry= input.nextInt();
    if (userEntry >= 0) {
        min = Math.min(min, userEntry);
        max = Math.max(max, userEntry);
    }
}
```

Let's simplify the problem with an array and a single loop.

```
int[] test = { 1, 2 };
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int userEntry : test) {
    min = Math.min(min, userEntry);
    max = Math.max(max, userEntry);
}
System.out.println("The max is : " + max);
System.out.println("The min is : " + min);
```

and I get

```
The max is : 2
The min is : 1
```

Comment: I tried this, but the max and min is both coming out the same. I tested 1 and 2. Both min and max came up as 2.

Comment: It's storing the max and min as the same values.